# Inner product formula used by numpy.dot

Tags: inner-products, tensor-products

Dot products are pretty simple for 1- or 2-dimensional arrays, but anything beyond that is incomprehensible to me. I tried looking into numpy‘s dot function but the C code is incomprehensible to me. What is the formula numpy is using to calculate the inner product of multidimensional arrays?

Comment: For future info, the doc is here (it’s still a good question though) https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html

Comment: @BenjaminWang believe me, I’ve spent a lot of time looking at numpy docs lol. I appreciate the help though.